# Is it right time to develope enterpize level applications in ASP.Net core 1.0?

Tags: asp.net

We are going to re-develop one of our lead management system and this will be in the latest Microsoft web technology. ASP.Net core 1.0 has release just. So, would like to know if this is a good candidate for such applications or we should wait for some more time?

Comment: Why you want to develop your application in `1.0` while you can use the latest versions ?

Comment: ASP.Net Core 1.0 is going to be the latest version. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'd be cautious, but perhaps even if still using ASP.NET 4.6 to make sure to rely on things that have a reasonable upgrade path - ie. not to use WebForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHICH TO CHOOSE?

To be clear, `ASP.NET 4.6` is the more mature platform. It's battle-tested and released and available today. `ASP.NET Core 1.0` is a `1.0` release that includes `Web API` and `MVC` but doesn't yet have `SignalR` or `Web Pages`. It doesn't yet support `VB` or `F#`.

It will have these subsystems some day but not today.

I don't want to recommended anyone to think that `ASP.NET Core 1.0` is the finish line. 
It's a new beginning and a fork in the road, but `ASP.NET 4.6` continues on, released and fully supported.

Thanks